# Find an ActionLink in UITestControl which has no id specified with it while using Hand coded UI method

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I want to use hand coded UI technique for UI testing of my ASP>NET MVC application.I have an a href  which resides inside a div container how do i find it using UITestControl?.

This is how the href is shown using

I am unable to spy this control using code Test Builder

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SOis not a place where you will find someone who will give you a ready made code. You will post what you have tried and you will get help if you get stuck. I understand you need a place to start, I would look at http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1055/hand-codedui-test-visual-studio-2013 to start with Hand Coding a Coded UI test

Comment: You should be able to use inspect element or view source in any browser to see what make up the definition of the targeted control. Knowing the HTML is critical for even attempting to help you.